# How to get google drive storage space quota API for android

Tags: android, google-drive-android-api, drive

How to get the google drive storage quota using Drive API for android.

The following link describes how to get a about resource file using Drive REST API which will contain information.

https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get#examples

I want to use the Drive API for android. How can I achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

Since the Drive Android API only supports Drive FILE scope currently, it does not provide this information. You would need to use the REST APIs for that.
I would also suggest to add a [feature request](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request&labels=Type-Enhancement,API-DriveAndroid) adding your use case so that the team working on the APIs can track it appropriately.

Comment: ... and you can 'hack it', by retrieving the ResourceId from the DriveId and applying the ResourceId to the REST call (GDAA.ResourceId = REST.id)